# Get a specific line from a variable

Tags: php, arrays, explode

how do I get only a specific line from a variable consisting of 10 or more lines?
I tried this code:

```
$line = explode('/n', $lines);
```

But now working.

This is my full code:

```
<?php
$line = explode('\r\n', "i
c");
echo $line[1];
?>
```

Comment: The newline is either `\r\n` or `\n`, so something like this should work: `$line = explode('\r\n', $lines); echo $line[1];`

Comment: @Cyclonecode i tried it, but i get all string in $line[0]

Comment: Can you add your data to your question?

Comment: Well, then you most likely are using the `\n` newline character so the code should be `$line = explode('\n', $lines); echo $line[1];`. You could also check for both type of newlines like this: `$line = explode('\n', str_replace("\r\n", $lines)); `. Like @Thefourthbird said - edit your question and add the data you are trying to parse.

Comment: @Cyclonecode i tried your method too

Comment: @Thefourthbird ok

Comment: I think you should write "\r\n" between double quotes, and maybe you only need the "\n".

Comment: If "\r\n" and "\n" aren't working..then there is no new line character, obviously...

Comment: @LucFortunato - **Edit your question and add the data you are trying to parse**

Comment: Use double quotes "\n" for special chars (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why explode doesn't work for you (it should).  I'll suggest `PHP_EOL` as a delimiter and see how that grabs you.  For sake of comparison, you could use `preg_match()` but this will be slower.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6e2e8d479cfae747e741aa44f45edddb9db38b6))

```
$string='line1
line2
line3 line 3
line4
line five
line 6
line 7
line eight
line 9
line 10
line eleven';

for($x=1; $x<10; $x+=2){  // $x is the targeted line number
    echo "$x preg_match: ";
    echo preg_match('/(?:^.*$\R?){'.($x-1).'}\K.*/m',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail';
    echo "\n  explode: ";
    echo explode(PHP_EOL,$string)[$x-1];
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output

```
1 preg_match: line1
  explode: line1
---
3 preg_match: line3 line 3
  explode: line3 line 3
---
5 preg_match: line five
  explode: line five
---
7 preg_match: line 7
  explode: line 7
---
9 preg_match: line 9
  explode: line 9
---
```

The more I think about it, you might be experiencing an issue with your quoting.  Single quotes will render `\n` as two non-white-space characters `\` and `n`.  You must use double quotes to have it treated like a newline character.

[Another demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5ac55c53188ec310d909045499a3657a09ee142):

```
echo 'PHP_EOL  ',explode(PHP_EOL,$string)[0];     // PHP_EOL works
echo "\n\n",'"\\n"  ',explode("\n",$string)[0];  // "\n" works
echo "\n\n","'\\n'  ",explode('\n',$string)[0];  // '\n' doesn't work, the newline character is "literally" interpreted as "backslash n"
```

Output:

```
PHP_EOL  line1     // This is correct

"\n"  line1        // This is correct

'\n'  line1        // The whole string is printed because there is no "backslash n" to explode on.
line2
line3 line 3
line4
line five
line 6
line 7
line eight
line 9
line 10
line eleven
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to split by line then you should use:

```
$line = explode("\n", $lines);
```

As an example:

```
<?php

$lines = "first line
second line
third line
fourth line";

$line = explode("\n", $lines);

echo $line[3];
```

This will give you `fourth line`. Remember that the first element in the array is 0, second is 1, third is 2 and so on ...

Comment: Yes... i tried it, but i get all string in $line[0]